# Incorrect Sum Of Rows in SQL Server after changing the insert order of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in a SQL Server database. I insert same values into both tables, only difference is the inserting order.

The sample values:

```
-422.82, 422.82, -407.78, 407.78
```

The `SUM` of the `ztFloat2` table is wrong.

I checked DATA PAGES of both tables. All the slot values are same. Is it a classic float datatype problem or a SQL Server BUG?

```
CREATE TABLE ztFloat1 ([Qty] [float] NOT NULL)

insert into ztFloat1 select -422.82
insert into ztFloat1 select  422.82
insert into ztFloat1 select -407.78
insert into ztFloat1 select  407.78

select SUM(Qty) from ztFloat1 -- **RESULT = 0** 


CREATE TABLE ztFloat2([Qty] [float] NOT NULL)

insert into ztFloat2 select -422.82
insert into ztFloat2 select -407.78
insert into ztFloat2 select  422.82
insert into ztFloat2 select  407.78

select SUM(Qty) from ztFloat2  --  **RESULT =-1,13686837721616E-13**
```

Note: the problem exists in all versions of SQL Server

Comment: Use decimal data type instead. (What you see is floating point behavior.)

Comment: Works for me in SQL Server, Postgres and Oracle without problems.

Comment: There is *no* inherent user-observable ordering to tables. The phrase "insert order" doesn't make sense. Tables are an *unordered* set of rows.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever but insert order really matters. Only difference is the order of records in the DB_PAGE.Maybe it is just coincidence.It is also same in VB.NET.Calculation order changes the result. Also changing the clustered index of table changes the result.
When i order the records by their Abs values it gives the true result.

        Dim a As Double = -422.82
        Dim b As Double = 422.82
        Dim c As Double = -407.78
        Dim d As Double = 407.78
        
        Immediate Window
        ?a+b+c+d
        0
        ?a+c+b+d
        5.6843418860808015E-14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice question. You need to define float value for ztFloat2 like below

```
CREATE TABLE ztFloat2([Qty] [float](24) NOT NULL)

insert into ztFloat2 select -422.82
insert into ztFloat2 select -407.78
insert into ztFloat2 select  422.82
insert into ztFloat2 select  407.78

select SUM(Qty) from ztFloat2
```

If you define float value more than 25 it will display result in exponential format. Below link is useful.

https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10177.data-types-approximate-numeric

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The float and real data types are known as approximate data types.

Refer Link : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx

You can fix this issue by converting to exact decimals like,

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(Qty) AS NUMERIC(18,6)) FROM ztFloat2
```